# SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (0)

Tags: php, sockets, email, ssl, smtp

I need to send a mail in order to reset the password, however I get this error everytime I click on the button to reset the password. I will post my code below:

```
require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');

                    $uri = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ;
                    $from_name = 'test';
                    $from = 'test@gmail.com';
                    $to = $email;
                    $to_name = 'test';
                    $message = 'Click on the given link to reset your password <a href="'.$uri.'/reset.php?token='.$token.'">Reset Password</a></p>';

                    $message .= 'Regards<br>';
                    $message .= 'test';

                    $mail = new PHPMailer();
                    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                    $mail->IsSMTP();    
                    $mail->Port = 587; // or 587                         // set mailer to use SMTP
                    $mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.mandrillapp.com";  // specify main and backup server
                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
                    $mail->Username = '****************';  // SMTP username
                    $mail->Password = '****************'; // SMTP password      // SMTP account password

                    $mail->SetFrom($from,$from_name );
                    $mail->AddReplyTo($from,$from_name );
                    $mail->Subject  = 'Password Change';
                    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
                    $mail->AddAddress($to,$to_name);

                    if(!$mail->Send())
                    {
                        echo "sorry!";
                    }
```

I have seen posts which say I need to change/uncomment an extension which is for open_ssl.dll. I cannot find the line anywhere in the php.ini file or the php-5.3.ini. I am using Ampps on Ubuntu 14.04. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it resolved, in the Ampps App itself, there is a PHP tab, Went there, clicked PHP extensions and found openssl extension. Checked it, Hit Apply. Restarted Ampps and Voila! SMTP SERVER up and running.

**PROCEDURE:**
Ampps->PHP Tab->PHP extensions->enable openssl->Apply->Restart Ampps.